# C++ string::size_type error

Tags: c++

I'm using visual studio 2013 community to study c++ primer.
And I encounter this problem.
When I write  the following code,VS shows that len is undefined.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
int main()
{
    string line;
    while (getline(cin, line))
        if (line.size() > 10)
            auto len = line.size();
            cout << line.size() <<" "<<len <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I write  the following code, VS shows that len is defined and works well.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
int main()
{
    string line("fewogwewjgeigeoewggwe");
            auto len = line.size();
            cout << line.size() <<" "<< len <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I really don't see the reason about it. Hoping for some good explanations. Thx a lot!!!

Comment: C++ isn't like Python where indentation is significant. The output is not inside the `if` *or* the loop.

Comment: In the first block of code the 'cout' line isn't within the "if" block since there's no braces... thus the 'len' variable is already out of scope.  Add some braces.

Comment: Thank u all very much. My first question on SO. very happy to see answers so quick!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should write proper code blocks using curly braces. At your 1st sample `len` is out of scope

```
    if (line.size() > 10)
        auto len = line.size(); // <<< scope is local to this line
    cout << line.size() <<" "<<len <<endl;
```

what you want is

```
    if (line.size() > 10) { // <<<
        auto len = line.size(); // <<< scope is local to the block
        cout << line.size() <<" "<<len <<endl;
    } // <<<
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing braces

```
if (line.size() > 10)
{
    auto len = line.size();
    cout << line.size() <<" "<<len <<endl;
}
```

The above should do it.

Update:

The first thing I do after learning a new programming language is to research for coding standard and stick to it. This will help in lot many ways including making such mistakes.

There are numerous coding standard for c++, so take your pick
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions#Coding_conventions_for_languages

Answer (score 1):

If you format your code, you will see your error

```
while (getline(cin, line))
if (line.size() > 10)
    auto len = line.size();            // variable len defined in this block ..
cout << line.size() <<" "<<len <<endl; // .. and not defined here
```